# How can i create a switch button in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I want to create a switch button like above[image]
I am a swt developer where i used to get this widget [Switchbutton](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/SwitchButton).
Can i have something similar in javafx

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html. I know it's not exactly the same, but serves basically the same functionality.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First inclination is to extend the JavaFX `Label` and add a `Button` as a graphic and a `SimpleBooleanProperty` for listening. Set an `ActionEvent` handler on the button that toggles the `Label`'s text, style, and graphic content alignment. The code below will get you started and you can play with styling and bounding.

```
package switchbutton;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class SwitchButton extends Label
{
    private SimpleBooleanProperty switchedOn = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

    public SwitchButton()
    {
        Button switchBtn = new Button();
        switchBtn.setPrefWidth(40);
        switchBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t)
            {
                switchedOn.set(!switchedOn.get());
            }
        });

        setGraphic(switchBtn);

        switchedOn.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov,
                Boolean t, Boolean t1)
            {
                if (t1)
                {
                    setText("ON");
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;-fx-text-fill:white;");
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
                }
                else
                {
                    setText("OFF");
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;-fx-text-fill:black;");
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
                }
            }
        });

        switchedOn.set(false);
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty switchOnProperty() { return switchedOn; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't this be done with two toggle buttons that are bound together (bind()) where each button get's it's own CSS styling?  It actually seems like the CSS would be the tricky (but doable) part to get right.

Then you would just have your app listen to the toggle button of the two that actually does what you want?

Comment: This is an answer. The answer says to bind together two toggle buttons that have distinct CSS styling. If you feel that that is wrong, a bad practice, or not useful, the correct behavior is to downvote the answer, not delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The controls FX project provides a switch button like you seek.